# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE special case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a CSV file, which contains something like the following:

```
NEW YORK, NYC
LOS ANGELES, LA
```

However, there is a special case which is

```
WASHINGTON,DC, DC
```

Because there are two comma in the washington case, I cannot load the file to DB properly since the table only has two columns.
I don't want to use java code to check each row contains more than one comma and edit the washington row to be "WASHINGTON, DC", DC.

I am wondering is there a way to rewrite my old LOAD DATA query to handle this special case?

Current incorrect result:

```
+--------+--------------+
| value  | mapped_value |
+--------+--------------+
| NEW YORK      | NYC       |
| LOS ANGELES   | LAX       |
| WASHINGTON    | DC        |
+--------+--------------+
```

The expected result should be look like this:

```
+--------+--------------+
| value  | mapped_value |
+--------+--------------+
| NEW YORK      | NYC       |
| LOS ANGELES   | LAX       |
| WASHINGTON,DC | DC        |
+--------+--------------+
```

Table Query:

```
CREATE TABLE city_map (value varchar(255) , mapped_value varchar(255));
```

My current "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" query is like following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/city.csv' INTO TABLE city_map FIELDS\n TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Comment: I think there is no params like this for `LOAD DATA`. Just add a third column, load data, and drop it if you do not need.  Or leave it, if this is a cronjob, or a repeated process.

Comment: @ karacsi_maci  I fixed LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE code, thanks

Comment: Does this file break when loaded into a spreadsheet application?

Comment: @Goose no break

Comment: @YiZhao then load it into a spreadsheet application and re-export, except set the deliminator to be something unique, such as | or ~. Is it okay if you change `Washington, DC` to say just `Washinton DC`

Comment: @Goose I can't change the delimiter and I can't use java or any languages to preprocess this file. This is the reasons why I want to resolve it from root cause by editing the "LOAD DATA" query.

Comment: @YiZhao so to be clear, you can not alter the file in any way? That may make this impossible. How would anything other than a human know which coma is the deliminator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV should also have a delimiter like double quote " to enclose your fields. A separator is not enough in a CSV.

If you open your CSV with a text editor you should see them, otherwise your CSV is not valid as you have more commas than needed.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/city.csv' INTO TABLE city_map FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

Comment: Cool, I think this is the only way to resolve this issue by changing the Load Data query to be yours and then to alter the csv to be like "WASHINGTON,DC","DC"